# Need clarity about ListData type

Tags: wcf, listdata.svc

I'm new into Sharepoint development.

I'm looking into a previously written console program that updates a list from a Sap database.
I've found this line of code where in I'm not able to find any resource on the ListData type:

```
ListData.ViewData view = null;
```

I need some clarity into exactly what kind of data type is it? (does it belong to system or sharepoint?). Also can someone throw some light on exactly how a windows communication foundation service is used? Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think there is also a WCF service available for this type as well.

Thanks for  your time !

Comment: Can you provide more clarity for that LisData.ViewData ??

Comment: Sorry it's ListData.ViewData. Upon further inspection I Realized that this is just dataTable being used by the previous programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can communicate with sharepoint through service(ListData.svc) which allows you to operations on the list. 
Please find below the microsoft link to teach how to communicate with these services
[Accessing SharePoint 2010 Lists by Using WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh134614%28v=office.14%29.aspx)